best method to do Django facial recognition by capturing the customer's camera
Good afternoon, what would be the best way to capture frames from the user's camera to use a function I have in Django views for facial recognition.
What I'm trying now is to open a camera for the user on the web and from there remove the frames, but it's not working correctly as it's giving me the error "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable" and also I wanted the user to have that frame around the face saying that the image is being captured.
I will send below what I have in views and in my js
I appreciate any help or opinion offered
type / value of face_recognition.run_recognition(frame): <generator object FaceRecognition.run_recognition at 0x0000021B45F53840>
FaceRecognition is a class where I have the variables and functions for facial recognition with openCV, where I get the images from the database to compare them with those being recognized in real time
@csrf_exempt
def process_frame_faceRecognition(request):
    print("Processando frame...")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frame_data = request.POST.get('frame_data')
        print(frame_data)
        frame_data = frame_data.split(',')[1]  # Remover o prefixo 'data:image/png;base64,'
        frame_data_decoded = base64.b64decode(frame_data)
        frame_data = np.frombuffer(frame_data_decoded, dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame_data, flags=1)
        
        # Agora você pode passar o frame para a função compare_faces()
        face_recognition = FaceRecognition()
        result = face_recognition.run_recognition(frame)

        # Verifique o tipo de resultado antes de retorná-lo
        if isinstance(result, HttpResponseRedirect):
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'redirecionamento', 'url': result.url})
        else:
            # Coleta os valores do generator em uma lista
            result_list = list(result)
            # Codifica a imagem como base64
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
            frame_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')
            print("hello world 2")
            return JsonResponse({'message': result_list, 'image': frame_base64})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Método não permitido'}, status=405)

HTMLJS
// Função para iniciar a câmera quando a página é carregada
window.onload = function() {
    startCamera();
};

// Função para iniciar a câmera
function startCamera() {
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Acessa a webcam do usuário
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);
        });

    // Função para capturar e processar o quadro da câmera
    function captureFrame() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // Obtém os dados do frame como uma imagem codificada em base64
        sendFrameToServer(imageData);
    }

    // Envia o frame capturado para o servidor
    function sendFrameToServer(frameData) {
        fetch('/process_frame_faceRecognition/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken') // Adicione o token CSRF
            },
            body: 'frame_data=' + encodeURIComponent(frameData) // Envia os dados do frame como POST data
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data.message === 'redirecionamento') {
                window.location.href = data.url;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending frame to server:', error);
        });
    }

    function processResponse(response) {
    // Verifica se a resposta possui a chave 'image'
        if ('image' in response) {
            // Obtém a imagem codificada em base64 da resposta
            var imageData = response.image;
            // Cria um elemento de imagem
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            // Define o atributo 'src' com os dados da imagem codificada
            img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
            // Adiciona a imagem ao corpo do documento (ou a qualquer outro elemento desejado)
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Andre\sk-access-control-ai\facialRecog\main\views.py", line 215, in process_frame_faceRecognition
    return JsonResponse({'message': result_list, 'image': frame_base64})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 733, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 106, in default
    return super().default(o)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre.pimentel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

FaceRecognition Class
class FaceRecognition: # Reconhecimento em Live Stream
    

    def __init__(self):
        # Obtem o endereço MAC do dispositivo atual
        self.mac_address = obter_mac_address()
        # Inicializa a lista de codificações de rostos conhecidos
        self.known_face_encodings = []
        # Inicializa a lista de nomes de rostos conhecidos
        self.known_face_names = []
        # Chama a função para codificar os rostos
        self.encode_faces()
        # Inicializa a lista de nomes de rostos reconhecidos
        self.face_names = []
        # Inicializa a contagem de rostos não reconhecidos
        self.no_face_count = 0

    def encode_faces(self):
        # Itera sobre todas as pessoas no banco de dados
        for pessoa in Pessoa.objects.all():
            # Carrega a imagem do rosto da pessoa
            face_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(pessoa.photo.path)
            # Verifica se há pelo menos um rosto na imagem
            if len(face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)) > 0:
                # Obtém a codificação do primeiro rosto na imagem
                face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
                # Adiciona a codificação do rosto à lista de codificações de rostos conhecidos
                self.known_face_encodings.append(face_encoding)
                # Adiciona o nome da pessoa à lista de nomes de rostos conhecidos
                self.known_face_names.append(pessoa.name)

    def run_recognition(self, frame):

        

        print(frame)
           
        self.last_face_names = []  


        rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Encontra as localizações das faces no frame
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
        # Captura as caracteristicas faciais
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
                    
        if len(face_encodings) >= 2: # Se houver mais de um rosto no frame
            self.no_face_count = 0
            print("Dois rostos na imagem.")
            face_names = []

            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"
                if True in matches:
                    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                    name = self.known_face_names[first_match_index]
                face_names.append(name)
                estacao_trabalho = EstacaoTrabalho.objects.get(mac_address=self.mac_address)
            
            for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), -1)
                cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)

// More code

What is the FaceRecognition class / function? Share the complete error traceback. What is the return type / value of face_recognition.run_recognition(frame)? Your question lacks important debugging details. Please ensure you share a [mre] with us.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for your comment and patience, I have already added the request in the comment, I hope this is what you are looking for, thank you for your opinion

Your code still lacks a [mre], looking at the traceback the error happens on the JsonResponse({'message': result_list, 'image': frame_base64}), given frame_base64 is probably a string, result_list likely contains something which is bytes. That basically comes from face_recognition.run_recognition(frame) and you haven't shared that code with us.

@AbdulAzizBarkat already added
